# Using A NSTimer for MM:SS:HS?

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I have created a NSTimer In Xcode 4.2 and it works but i get this one problem.

here is my project in the simulator

[image: simulator]

when i press start it starts and when i press stop it stops and when its stopped it will reset 
but when it starts and i press reset when it is going nothing happens it don't reset when started basically you have to stop then reset is the ways and this or do i need to add code any where heres a copy of my code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *time; 

    NSTimer *myticker;

    //declare baseDate
    NSDate* baseDate; 

}

-(IBAction)stop;
-(IBAction)reset;

@end
```

heres my implementation

```
 #import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize baseDate;


-(IBAction)start {
    [myticker invalidate];
    self.baseDate = [NSDate date];
    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)stop;{ 

    [myticker invalidate];
    myticker = nil;

}



-(IBAction)reset {
    self.baseDate = [NSDate date];
     time.text = @"00:00:0";  
}


-(void)showActivity {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [baseDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    double intpart;
    double fractional = modf(interval, &intpart);
    NSUInteger hundredth = ABS((int)(fractional*10));
    NSUInteger seconds = ABS((int)interval);
    NSUInteger minutes = seconds/60;

    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%01d", minutes%60, seconds%60, hundredth];
}
```

I Really Appreciate It. Thanks.

Comment: Please Guys I really need your help

Comment: Look at what the showActivity method does to show the time elapsed (understanding this code is the key).  Then look at the difference between what the start method does as opposed to the reset method.

Comment: @annakarenina i have but i been trying for about a day and still can't find a way can you help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the above should crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it reaches `showActivity` since `baseDate` is not being retained in the `start` method.  `[NSDate date]` returns an autoreleased object so `baseDate` will have an invalid reference after the `start` method.

I suggest changing `baseDate` to a `retain` property and then setting it in `start` using `self.`:

```
//.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *baseDate;

//.m
@synthesize baseDate;

-(IBAction)start {
    [myticker invalidate];
    self.baseDate = [NSDate date];
    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

To fix the `reset` problem, note that the `showActivity` method takes the current value of `baseDate` to calculate the elapsed time and then sets the `time` label to display it formatted.

In the `start` method, you set the `baseDate` to the current time (you don't set `time.text`) and then start the timer.  The `showActivity` method will then keep firing and set `time.text`.

In the `reset` method, you want the timer to start showing the elapsed time since the moment reset is pressed.  The timer is already running so you don't need to re-start it.  Setting the `time` label text doesn't work because when the already-running timer fires again, it will calculate the elapsed time from `baseDate` which is still the original start time and then set `time.text` based on that.  So instead of setting `time.text`, set the `baseDate`:

```
-(IBAction)reset {
    self.baseDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Comment: im :? can you do me a huge favour and edit my answer with your answer i really don't understand what you mean (please add this code to my code thank you)

Comment: You need to do four things: 1) Add the `@property` line in the .h right above the IBAction lines.  2) Add the `@synthesize` line in the .m after the `@implementation` line.  3) Change the code in the start method as shown.  4) Change the code in the reset method as shown.

Comment: hi that works now but it won't reset when its stopped now ?? thanks so much so far

Comment: Understand the code and just think about what you want to happen and try something.

Comment: -(IBAction)reset {
    self.baseDate = [NSDate date];
}  or should it just be this

Comment: You're close.  The stop method is where you want to add the `time.text = @"00:00:00";` after disabling the timer.

Comment: So add time.text = @"00:00:00"; to -(IBAction)stop;{ 

    [myticker invalidate];
    myticker = nil;
}
?/

Comment: Yes, after setting setting myticker to nil.  Here you have to set the label directly because showActivity will no longer fire and override the setting.

Comment: i have sorted that out but for some reason it counts up deferentially  i placed that text in the reset and it worked but counted up like 00:00:0 which i don't mind but ever time i press start it goes to 00:00:00 but the last one does nothing how can i get reid of it

Comment: ^do you known what i can change

Comment: i have edit my code at the top it now counts up like 00:00:0 fine but when the seconds get to 00:08:0 it counts like this 00:08:3 00:08:7 00:08:9 00:09:3 if you known what i mean I'm now lost :(

Comment: I don't know why didn't add the line to the stop method (though that has nothing to do with your latest comment).  Setting the time.text in the reset method doesn't do anything.  Anyway, in showActivity, I don't know why you changed the `*100` to `*10` and the `%02d` to `%01d`.  But these changes or problems have nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: i known i have only just changed these because it worked abit better but when i but the time.text in reset button it now resets

Comment: i want it to count up like the stopwatch in the iPhone